# Checking if the first letter of string is in uppercase in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to check if the first letter of string is in uppercase in Dart language. How can I implement it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you simply want to check it or do you need know and act upon it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to compare the first letter of the string with the uppercase equivalent of it. Something like:

```
bool isUpperCase(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (string.isEmpty) {
      return false;
    }
    if (string.trimLeft().isEmpty) {
      return false;
    }
    String firstLetter = string.trimLeft().substring(0, 1);
    if (double.tryParse(firstLetter) != null) {
      return false;
    }
    return firstLetter.toUpperCase() == string.substring(0, 1);      
}
```

Updated the answer to take in consideration digits.

Also @Saed Nabil is right, this solution will return true if the string starts with any character that is not a letter (except for digits).

Comment: Great ,but I think it will give wrong answer if the string starts with a number or any other Glyph rather than Alphabets

Comment: Perfect. Without any library. Thank you!

Comment: Perfectly. Perfect.. Thanks for Giving so Broad Answers. Love you Love you alot. Thanks for helping and this will be eternally thanked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `validators` library if you are not already using it.
Then use this method

> isUppercase(String str) → bool
> check if the string str is uppercase

Don't forget to import the ***dependency***, [see documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/validators), to the `pubspec.yaml` and to your code `import 'package:validators/validators.dart';`.

##### Example code:

```
if(isUppercase(value[0])){
  ... do some magic
}
```

You should check that the `value` is ***not empty*** and ***not*** `null` first for safety. Like this:

```
if(value != null && value.isNotEmpty && isUppercase(value[0])){
  ... do amazing things
}
```

Comment: rather than negating `!value.isEmpty` why don't you use `value.isNotEmpty`?

Comment: This is returning true for $ for example. I combined it with isAlpha

Answer (score 1):

Verify the ascii code of the character using [codeUnites](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.5/dart-core/String/codeUnits.html)

Add this extension

```
extension Case on String{
    // isuppercase
    bool isUpperCase(){
        int ascii = codeUnitAt(0);
        return ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90;
    }
    // islowercase
    bool isLowerCase(){
        int ascii = codeUnitAt(0);
        return ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122;
    }
}
```

use it like this

```
String letter = 'A';
print(letter.isUpperCase()); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code it will return the actual uppercase letter else will return null

```
void main(){
  var myString = "1s you said";
  var firstCapital = firstCapitalLetter(myString);

  if( firstCapital != null){
    print("First Capital Letter is ${firstCapital}");
  }else{
    print("Not found");
  }
}
String firstCapitalLetter(String myString){

  final allCapitals = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //string.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() == string.substring(0, 1) will not work with for ex. numbers;

   if (myString == null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (myString.isEmpty) {
      return null;
    }
    if (myString.trimLeft().isEmpty) {
      return null;
    }

  if( allCapitals.contains(myString[0])){
       return myString[0];
  }else{
       return null;
  }
 }
```

this is a typical case for Optional type of Java language , please check this library if you prefer functional style code
[optional package](https://pub.dev/packages/optional)

Comment: yes, but you can add the deferent languages you are interested in

Comment: Advice: Don't do language handeling, ABC, 诶比尺, let the dart framwork do that work for you.

Comment: @HarounHajem please, check the implementation of validators package it uses RegExp in the same way i.e ' RegExp _alpha = new RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$');`  I already explained why I came up with this solution, other solutions will give wrong answer when the string start with for example numbers.

Comment: Oohh, didn't know that it used an RegEx for A-Z. That's really bad. =S

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isUppercase(String str){
    return str == str.toUpperCase();
  }
```

This seems to be elegant way for checking uppercase

```
String s='Hello';

bool isUpper = isUppercase(s[0]);
print(isUpper);  //true

isUpper = isUppercase(s[1]);
print(isUpper);  //false
```